# Plotly subplots with shared range-slider

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have three subplots sharing the same range-slider. The animation in general works fine, however when I run the fig.show(), the first figure outputs looks like this:
[Incorrect output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zR1DU.png)

Thus, it includes all the data at once. When I drag the slider back and forth it properly updates and includes the right amount of bars (10 on each subplot).

[Correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EghF0.png)
I seems that it is only the first print-out of the plots that is somehow messed up.
As I plan to post the figure on a website and have it update automatically, I need it to look right when it is first printed. My code looks like this:

```
fig = make_subplots(3, 1, subplot_titles=('Politiske', 'Generelt', "Nødhjælp"))

#"tid" is a list of "week number, year", which the data is sorted into: ["1, 2021", "2, 2021", "3,2021" ... etc]

for step in tid:
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
        orientation='h',
        name="Politiske",
        x=pol[pol['uge_år'] == step]['id'],
        y=pol[pol['uge_år'] == step]['page_name'],
        marker = {'color': rødbrun}
        ), row =1, col=1)

for step in tid:
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
        orientation='h',
        name="Generelt",
        x=gen[gen['uge_år'] == step]['id'],
        y=gen[gen['uge_år'] == step]['page_name'],
        marker = {'color': mørkegrå}
        ), row=2, col=1)


for step in tid:
   fig.add_trace(
        go.Bar(
        orientation='h',
        name="Nødhjælp",
        x=nød[nød['uge_år'] == step]['id'],
        y=nød[nød['uge_år'] == step]['page_name'], 
        marker = {'color': lysegrå}
        ), row=3, col=1)


# Create and add slider
steps = []

for i in range(len(tid)):

step = dict(
    method="update",  #"update",
    label= tid[i],
    args=[{"visible": [False] * len(tid)},
          {"title": ""}])

step["args"][0]["visible"][i] = True  # Toggle i'th trace to "visible"
steps.append(step)


sliders = [dict(
active=0,
currentvalue={"prefix": "Uge, År: "},
pad={"t": 50},
steps=steps)]


fig.update_layout(sliders=sliders)



 fig.update_layout(showlegend = False,  plot_bgcolor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', 
    font=dict(
    family="Work Sans",
    size=14,
    color="Black")) 


 fig.update_xaxes(showticklabels=True, showline=True, linewidth=0.5, linecolor='black', title = '')
 fig.update_xaxes(col=1, row=3, title = 'Antal Annoncer')
 fig.update_yaxes(showticklabels=True, showline=True, linewidth=0.5, linecolor='black', title=' ')


 fig.show()
```

My figure data looks like this:
[figure.data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAthm.png)

Comment: Is there code that limits the number of bars at the point of creation?

Comment: The data already limited to 10 observations (per plot) for each step. I have added a print-out of the figure.data()

Comment: What is the output of `len(tid)?`

Comment: It is just a list of week numbers, corresponding to the steps on the range slider

Comment: But how long is it? You are looping over `tid` doing `fig.add_trace` for each value of tid. If it is long (i.e. 52 weeks) then it would explain why you have so much data in your charts.

Comment: It has a length of 14. But my three datasets (pol, gen and nød) have 10 observations for each week - thus figure.data has 45 Bar plots (15 for each of the datasets mentioned above), and each of these 45 plots has 10 observations. Again, the plots works fine when I drag the slider back and forth, but the first print of fig.show() somehow includes all the bars at once